# Can't connect Filebeat to Logstash

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am new to `elasticsearch` and I am following the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7):

I have hit a stumbling block as I can connect the servers with the `ELK-stack` configured with the server that is logging activity to `FileBeat`.

I have narrowed it down to an issue with the SSL certificates copied from the ELK server as when i check `/var/log/messages` I get the following error:

> usr/bin/filebeat[13730]: transport.go:125: SSL client failed to
>   connect with: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly
>   because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify
>   candidate authority certificate "serial:16193853809450343771")

How ever, the keys have been copied over and these files are the same on both servers :

```
cat /etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt
```

When I try to read the syslogs, I get the following message :

```
sudo tail /var/log/syslog | grep filebeat:

tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/syslog’ for reading: No such file or directory.
```

I will appreciate any pointers on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a similar issue in the `elastic` forum in the following [link](http://Does%20Filebeat%20connect%20fine%20if%20you%20add%20the%20insecure:%20true%20option%20to%20your%20Filebeat%20tls%20config?%20%20If%20so,%20then%20you%20probably%20have%20a%20cert%20issue.%20You%20can%20check%20the%20docs%20on%20how%20to%20test%20the%20certs%20independently%20of%20Filebeat.%20https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-tls-logstash.html).
In summery, You should add to your `FileBeat`config:
`insecure: true`

And than see if you manage to connect. If you do, you can use this [guidelines for how to configure your ssl connection](http://%20https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-tls-logstash.html)